# How to avoid instanceof in search routines?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Currently, I'm performing a linear search on a list of items like so:

```
private Item getKey(ArrayList<Item> inventory) {
    for(Item item : inventory) {
        if(item instanceof Key) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've heard that it is considered a "code smell" to use `instanceof`. Usually to avoid the use of `instanceof` I would use polymorphism (such as what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953608/avoiding-instanceof-java)), however, in a case like this I'm struggling to see how I could use that.

So I'm wondering if there is a way I could remove the need of `instanceof` and perhaps use another technique such as polymorphism which is more OOD focused?

Comment: You need to zoom out. The flaw is not in this method. It's in the very fact that you're trying to extract a `Key` from a list of `Item`.

Comment: @shmosel ah, I see what you mean. Any ideas of a better approach to represent the inventory? Do you think maybe an additional `Inventory` class would help?

Comment: Hard to say without more context.

Comment: @shmosel ok, I understand. Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a solution that uses polymorphism instead of `instanceof`, you need to define an `isKey()` method in your supertype, and override it for subtypes that qualify as keys:

```
public class Item {

    public boolean isKey() { 
        return false; 
    }
}

class Key extends Item {
    @Override
    public boolean isKey() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then your solution becomes:

```
private Item getKey(ArrayList<Item> inventory) {
    for(Item item : inventory) {
        if(item.isKey()) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that this will return the *first* key in your inventory.

For a more modern (and compact) code style, you can leverage your predicate method `isKey()` in a [stream](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) operation and return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) instead of a possibly null key:

```
private Optional<Item> getKey(ArrayList<Item> inventory) {
    return inventory.stream().filter( item -> item.isKey() ).findFirst();
}
```

Comment: This is still flawed on the same level. Similarly, you could create an `int type` field (or an `enum Type` field, for that matter). But it all breaks down if you have a list of `Item` objects, and then want to dissect them to obtain the `Key`, `Foo`, `Bar` and `Smurf` objects out of it. The question is: Why are objects stored in the same list when they are **so** conceptually different that it is afterwards necessary to split them by their type? Probably, they should be stored in different lists in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Your case is difference from your link. I don't think your code in this case is a "code smell".
As @shmosel mentions

> The flaw is not in this method.

But you can make your code more reusable as:

```
private Item getKey(ArrayList<Item> inventory) {
    return getAnItemByType(inventory, Key.class);
}
private Item getAnItemByType(ArrayList<Item> inventory, Class<? extends Item> type) {
    for(Item item : inventory) {
        if(type.isInstance(item)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```